# User search box is disabled

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, users

For some reason, the user search box on the redesigned users page is disabled. Enabling it with something like firebug still doesn't work. I presume this has something to do with the in-development redesign, but was this done on purpose or is it a bug? It's rather inconvenient not being able to find a user when I want to search for them, and Google doesn't seem to have any easy way to search for users on stack exchange sites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>We disabled this for performance reasons, it was causing some pretty heavy load for a combination of reasons.  Worry not though, [waffles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/17174/waffles) is working on a new and improved method as I write this, the search box will make a return soon...along with some other enhancements to `/users` as well ;)</strike>

The search is back in full substring glory.

Answer (score 1):

It seems this has been done deliberately, since there's a "`disabled`" property in the input field. I think they might still be working on the search function. Some development or testing might be going on at the moment.

The latest blog-entry shows the search-field enabled, so I assume it got disabled later on.

Answer (score 1):

They are currently fixing some performance problems they had with user search

[HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81606/http-error-503-the-service-is-unavailable)